# Selcet html element from page through htmlstring using jquery

Tags: jquery

My issue is: I have a html string, that is also on web page.

Now I want that this html string should work as selector for jQuery.

Here is the doc html

```
<body>
   <p>asdf</p>
   <p>ghjk</p>
</body>
```

Now we have a string

```
 '<p><asdf</p>'
```

now

```
$('<p><asdf</p>').css("border",'1px solid red')
```

should read that paragraph border on document.

Any help will be appreciated!

fidlle:http://jsfiddle.net/eJxDb/2/

Comment: I think you need the [contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/): `$('p:contains(asdf)').css("border",'1px solid red')`

Comment: I have tried contians selector but it is not applying on rendered document.

Comment: this question does not make any sense.

Comment: Why @Jai?, I need solution and tried a lot.

Comment: i mean if the text is dynamic then why should we check for text to apply css to it.

Comment: let see i have some html string save in database, now i want that where these strings found in page apply a class on that element.so how we will do that?

Comment: contains should work in this case. do you have the string inside the element `asdf` in your database or all the HTML of the element `<p>asdf</p>` ?

Comment: Please check my fiddle in question @MarOnii, i ll need your help, i have all the html

Comment: @developerCK Try the solution I just post below tell me if it work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parseHTML and the html() function of JQuery :

**Exemple :**

http://jsfiddle.net/N6s8F/1/

**JavaScript :**

```
var obj = "<p>asdf</p>"
selector = $.parseHTML(obj)[0].nodeName;
text = $(obj).html();
console.log(text);
$(selector).each(function(index) {
console.log($(this).html());
console.log(text);
if ($(this).html() == text) {
    $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
    }
});
```

Comment: can we optimize that ?

Comment: Probably, You can delete the console logs :D and you will have only 4 lines of code. After that I don't see any optimization to apply.

Comment: actually i am taking about comparing, gathering and looping.

Comment: With the information you have to retreive the element I dont see any way but it may be before like when you get the string or how it is store in the database that need to be optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Give the paragraph id and the select it via id like this:

```
<p id="myID"><asdf</p>
```

And your jQuery:

```
('#myID').css("border",'1px solid red');
```

Comment: It is very dynamic , and result is not for any particular!